# Implement custom i18n fragments in Sails

Tags: node.js, sails.js

The existing `i18n` service is pretty good in Sails when it comes to short strings and messages, however, I want to extract parts of the templates into a so-called fragments in Markdown format and require them from the templates.

I've created the following structure:

- locales/fragments/en/index/introduction.md
- locales/fragments/ru/index/introduction.md

Now I want to include one of this fragments according to the active locale in the template:

```html
<section class="introduction">
    <h2>Introduction</h2>
    {{ fragment('index.introduction') }}
</section>
```

What is the best way to extend Sails to support this type of fragments?

1. How do I expose `fragment` function to the view layer? Where do I define this function?
2. How do I get current active locale in order to know what file to load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The Library

I've created [a library](https://github.com/betsol/sails-hook-i18n-fragment) to handle such use case. The code below is incorporated into this library.

## The Solution

1. The `fragment` function could be exposed using Expresses [`res.locals`](http://expressjs.com/3x/api.html#res.locals) property. You can access it in the hook via `routes`.
2. Current locale is exposed via [`req.getLocale()`](https://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node#getlocale) function.

And here's the complete code for the hook that I've produced:

```js
module.exports = function (sails) {

  var deasync = require('deasync');
  var fs = require('fs');
  var marked = require('marked');

  var configKey = 'i18n-fragment';

  var activeLocale;

  var defaults = {};
  defaults[configKey] = {
    path: 'locales/fragments/{locale}/{path}.md'
  };

  return {

    defaults: defaults,

    routes: {
      before: {
        '/*': function (request, response, next) {

          if (request.accepted.some(function (type) {
              return type.value === 'text/html';
            })) {
            activeLocale = request.getLocale();
            response.locals.fragment = deasync(getFragment);
          }

          next();
        }
      }
    }

  };

  function getFragment (address, callback) {
    var path = getFragmentPath(address, activeLocale);
    fs.readFile(path, 'utf8', function (error, source) {
      if (error) {
        return callback(error);
      }
      marked(source, callback);
    });
  }

  function getFragmentPath (address, locale) {
    return sails.config[configKey].path
      .replace('{locale}', locale)
      .replace('{path}', address.replace('.', '/'))
    ;
  }

};
```

Comment: You really shouldn't use `deasync` library

Comment: Why? What the alternative?

Comment: This library is broken from the beginning. It's just a hack that works in some cases but fails in others. There are no alternatives though, you should use asynchronous functions.